# Unable to load external R object with load()

Tags: r

I saved R objects in .Rdata files with `save(obj, filename)` but now I'm unable to load these objects in my global environment with `load(filename)`.

Files are created in my hard disk with a size around 4.2ko so I guess they contain the data but Rstudio can't load them and `load()` returns no error.

What can I do to load these data, or at least verify the data are present ?

EDIT: When redirecting `load()` I can see the data is only a character string and I'm very disappointed of not being able to restore these data. It is true that I should have tested the file restoration earlier, but is there still a hope ? a file of 4.2ko must contain data.

```
> MYR <- load("/home/R/data/MYR.Rdata")
> MYR
[1] "data"
> class(MYR)
[1] "character"
```

Comment: Type `str(data)` in your console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how load works ([see](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/load.html)).

It loads the data in the *environment* and return only a *list of names* of objects created.

So in your case an object named data has been loaded in the environment.  You can confirm with `ls()` it is there.  And of course you can inspect the object `data`.

Comment: Thanks, yes an object `data` has been created :)